# Ubuntu- no package called shinydashboard?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, shiny

I'm trying to set my shiny app up on AWS.  I've spent all day working on this and I keep running into issues- it's a bit maddening.  I saw that there was someone else that had a post about this same issue, but none of those solutions have worked for me.

I've installed shinydashboard (and all the other libraries I need for this app) from the server, in putty, using root, sudo, shiny.  When I go into R in either interface and use `library(shinydashboard)` it loads.  But the IP:3838 WILL NOT load for me.  I just get an error message saying that the page doesn't exist.

Can anyone help me or help get me pointed in the right direction?

Comment: Did you actually start a shiny application of some sort? The `library()` just loads the package but doesn't serve any site by default. What are you hoping to find at `IP:3838`?

Comment: Yup, I have a shiny app built that I tested out on shiny.io before trying AWS.  I pulled it in with a clone from a private github repo.  The code's good and all the data is there.  I just cant see the app. 

IP:3838 is the IP address and the shiny port.  All the reading online I've done lead me to believe that it should be there.  The sample one was there after I connected to shiny server.

Comment: Check the shiny server log. Check you installed the app in the right directory (and check that the url points to the directory that contains app.R or ui.R/server.R). Check shiny server status (could be `sudo systemctl status shiny-server`, that's the command for CentOS, I'm not sure for Ubuntu). Check that you can access the server (open ports in AWS console, or simply open a tiny java or python server on port 3838 and check if you can see something).

Comment: How do I check/adjust the directory? I was wondering about that. Git uploaded my app and the two csvs as a folder. 

I’m brand new to Linux.  The log history says it’s the library.  Which I’ve installed (no joke) at least a dozen times.

Comment: "The log history says it’s the library": says what, precisely? Fails on `library(...)` in your code? Then this would mean that the server sees the requests (so it's not a network problem) and finds the file (so it's not a directory problem), and that would eliminate several possibilities. Please be accurate.

Comment: Another point: depending on *how* you installed your libraries, there may be a problem with that too. If you installed as root, it should be ok. Otherwise R will probably install the package in the user directory, which will not be accessible by Shiny. When installing in non-system directories (i.e. not in /usr), you have to play with the service configuration files to tell the server where to find packages. Note also that on Linux packages are installed from source: check compilation errors when you install (there may be Linux packages missing, or wrong version of them).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, thank you for your answers.  

Here is the error message I got in the logs last night 

`su: ignoring --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive with --login
Error in library(shinydashboard) :
  there is no package called ‘shinydashboard
Calls: runApp ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> library
Execution halted`

Comment: Then this library isn't installed, or not installed in a directory where Shiny Server can find it. How did you install the library?

Comment: `$ sudo su - shiny
$ R
>install.packages("shinydashboard")`

Comment: I've also logged in as the root user and done the same process.  I logged in as root, opened R and entere `.libPaths()` and got `[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" [2] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"`.   I also ran `library(shinydashboard)` and it loaded, giving me this message. `> library(shinydashboard)

Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    box
`

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two issues going.

First, per your title. The package exists in the Rutter PPAs:

```
edd@rob:~$ apt-cache policy r-cran-shinydashboard
r-cran-shinydashboard:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.7.1-1
  Version table:
     0.7.1-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
edd@rob:~$
```

So if you know about those, it is a simple `sudo apt install r-cran-shinydashboard`.

Second, you may have configuration issues with Shiny.  I would try to make sure you can run the simplest 'hello world' example of the Old Faithful histogram before trying more advanced steps.  For example, there may be networks ports blocked not allowing you to export the Shiny port.

Our Rocker Project has a container with Shiny preinstalled. Maybe that can help...  See https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny

Comment: Thank you, Dirk.  I used that first portion and I got this. 

`$ apt-cache policy r-cran-shinydashboard
r-cran-shinydashboard:
  Installed: 0.7.1-1
  Candidate: 0.7.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.7.1-1 500
        500 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
`

I'll try switch out to a less complex shiny app though to see if that helps.